# Oracle's NCHR() function is behaving differently across platforms. How to fix?

Tags: windows, linux, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am encountering an issue with some Oracle code which uses the NCHR function.  The same code is running on Windows/Ora10g and Linux/Ora11g, yet it behaves differently.

The NLS characterset is identical on both instances.

I am trying to determine if this is an issue with Oracle versions or because of the OS.

Has anyone encountered this before?  If so, how do I fix?

Answer (score 3):

[NCHR in Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions091.htm)
The outcome of NCHR does not depend on the database NLS characterset. It depends on the client NLS characterset. The default client NLS_LANG setting on windows set by installer is different than linux.